# Free Pascal - Write File and append image to it

Tags: delphi-2010, freepascal, lazarus

I have an application for registration which saves customer information in a file that is a file for each client, using

```
Write(myFile, customer);
CloseFile(myFile);
FileMode := fmOpenReadWrite;
```

But I need to attach a picture [jpg] of the customer and puts it into the file, does anyone have any idea how can I do this?

This a complete List os records

```
type
   TCustomer = Record

     NomeCompleto : string[100];
     Nome : string[20];
     Sobrenome : string[20];
     Idade  : string[20];
     Sexo : string[20];
     Escolaridade:string[60];
     CPF: string[11];
     RG:string[20];
     EstadoCivil:string[20];
     Filhos: boolean;
     QTFilhos: string[10];
     Foto:string[255];
     Endereco:string[40];
     Numero: string[20];
     Bairro: string[20];
     Cidade:string[20];
     Estado:string[2];
     Telefone:string[10];
     Celular:string[10];
     Email:string[40];
     Adicionais: string[200];
     Objetivo: string[200];

     Experiencia1: string[45];
     Entrada1: string[4];
     Saida1: string[4];
     Cargo1: string[35];
     resumo1: string[200];

     Experiencia2: string[45];
     Entrada2: string[4];
     Saida2: string[4];
     Cargo2: string[35];
     resumo2: string[200];

     Experiencia3: string[45];
     Entrada3: string[4];
     Saida3: string[4];
     Cargo3: string[35];
     resumo3: string[200];

     Experiencia4: string[45];
     Entrada4: string[4];
     Saida4: string[4];
     Cargo4: string[35];
     resumo4: string[200];

   Instituicao1:string[45];
   Nomecurso1:string[45];
   datainicial1:string[45];
   datafinal1:string[45];

   Instituicao2:string[45];
   Nomecurso2:string[45];
   datainicial2:string[45];
   datafinal2:string[45];

   Instituicao3:string[45];
   Nomecurso3:string[45];
   datainicial3:string[45];
   datafinal3:string[45];

   Instituicao4:string[45];
   Nomecurso4:string[45];
   datainicial4:string[45];
   datafinal4:string[45];

   Instituicao5:string[45];
   Nomecurso5:string[45];
   datainicial5:string[45];
   datafinal5:string[45];

   Instituicao6:string[45];
   Nomecurso6:string[45];
   datainicial6:string[45];
   datafinal6:string[45];

   instituicao:string[45];
   area:string[45];
   ano:string[10];

   carga1:string[10];
   carga2:string[10];
   carga3:string[10];
   carga4:string[10];
   carga5:string[10];
   carga6:string[10];

   personalidade:string[255];
```

Comment: Just store the path and filename of the file, and keep the image separate. Trying to wedge a binary (jpg) file into a text file is going to turn into something nasty very quickly.

Comment: OK, thanks, but I need the file generated by my application may be sent by e-mail and opened by the same application on another computer, so loading the image. Any help?

Comment: Yes. Send the image file as an attachment to the email. When your software on the client side receives the email and processes it, it saves the attachment and (if needed) updates the record to show the location of the image file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop using old-style Pascal file I/O and embrace file streams.  Write your file as a binary file, not a text file.  Then you can do something like the following at a minimum.

To create the file:

```
var
  customer: TCustomer;
  jpg: TJPEGImage;
  myFile: TFileStream;
begin
  jpg := TJPEGImage.Create;
  try
    // fill customer and jpg as needed...
    myFile := TFileStream.Create(Filename, fmCreate);
    try
      myFile.WriteBuffer(customer, sizeof(customer));
      jpg.SaveToStream(myFile);
    finally
      myFile.Free;
    end;
  finally
    jpg.Free;
  end;
end;
```

To load the file:

```
var
  customer: TCustomer;
  jpg: TJPEGImage;
  myFile: TFileStream;
begin
  jpg := TJPEGImage.Create;
  try
    myFile := TFileStream.Create(Filename, fmOpenRead);
    try
      myFile.ReadBuffer(customer, sizeof(customer));
      jpg.LoadFromStream(myFile);
    finally
      myFile.Free;
    end;
    // use customer and jpg as needed...
  finally
    jpg.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: It could be a little clearer? I could not understand where each block of code should be used

Answer (score 0):

Given that your `customer` record contains fixed sized items, I'd suggest defining something like:

```
photo : byte[20000];
```

You can then open the JPG file as a `file of byte`, read all of it in, and store that in the `photo` array in your record.

Of course this has the downside that you will have to decide upfront what the maximum image size will be, but for a small face photo, 20-50kB should be more than enough.

It is also possible to reopen the file as a file of type `byte`, and simply append the binary image data to the end (ie, read the image data in as a `byte` array or sequence of bytes, and copy/append that to the customer data file), provided your `customer` record (as it is now) is of a fixed size.  This way, you know the 'balance' of your data file is pure image data.

Comment: The files will be different depending on the information used by the user and also the size of the picture display sizes. How could I do this?

Comment: What does your `customer` record look like?  If it's fixed sizes, the blob of binary stored on disk should be constant as well.  Otherwise, you'd have to go with the option of actually inserting the JPG binary data into the customer record.

Comment: Actually I created the app to streamline some procedures, such as creating a CV. Depending on the information that the customer enter the file size varies, especially in the case of CV, when customers insert an image. At the end of the process I want the user to save all the work entered, including the photo, in a single file, so that it can send and resume where you left off on another computer. My problem is the photo....

Comment: How do you handle the other variable sized data?  Can you handle the image (which is really just going to be a variable sized array of bytes) in the same way?

Comment: type
   TCustomer = Record

     name: string[20];
     lastname: string[20]; 
var
  myFile   : File of TCustomer;  // A file of customer records
  customer : TCustomer;

Comment: And to load  editname.text:=customer.name;
   editlastname.Text:=customer.lastname;

Comment: Those aren't variable fields though - they're all fixed length arrays.

Comment: So how do I do from there?

Comment: Can you update your post and include a complete listing of your customer record?  I might be able to give a better answer then.

Comment: Everything in the list is fixed size.  Just set a size limit for the photo (20-50k for a mugshot is plenty), and include it as an array of bytes.

Comment: The reason the filesize varies is because it likely gets stored without padding.

Comment: OK, thanks, but, how to include the photo into a array?

Comment: My answer above explains that, but I will try to clarify a bit.